# Value https of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: java, json, mongodb

I am trying to get Json String from json Array but got this error, Any help will be highly appreciated, Json formate is given bellow please help someone.
Error is as bellow

```
05-29 12:37:22.600 25505-25505/com.akasha.mongodataapi W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value https of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
05-29 12:37:22.610 25505-25505/com.akasha.mongodataapi W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
05-29 12:37:22.610 25505-25505/com.akasha.mongodataapi W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:96)
05-29 12:37:22.610 25505-25505/com.akasha.mongodataapi W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:108)
```

It is the Json Formate

```
 [ { "_id" : { "$oid" : "57472009a0fdab7cc3c"} , "name" : "Sasha Burni" , "sort" : "Sasha"} ,
 { "_id" : { "$oid" : "57472009afdab7cc3d"} , "name" : "Akasha Khail" , "sort" : "Akasha"}]
```

And the Java Code is as bellow

```
 String url="https://api.mlab.com/api/1/databases/picasanovels/collections/Country?apiKey=myapikey";

    try {
                JSONArray jArr = new JSONArray(url);
                for (int count = 0; count < jArr.length(); count++) {
                    JSONObject obj = jArr.getJSONObject(count);
                    String name = obj.getString("name");
                    System.out.println("Name Printed :"+name);
                    //so on
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: It looks like it's trying to convert your url into a JSON array. You have to make a GET request to get the contents of that URL and then pass the contents as an argument in making the JSONArray object

Comment: Are you not converting url thats a String to json array?  I guess you want to convert the response of the http request, which you are not making.

Use some http client like Unirest or apache http client to make request.

Comment: Thanks for early response , but if some example will be much understandable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. You are trying passing the API call (url address) to JSON ARRAY. It should be the response from the API call.
2. You have to create a URL object and pass the Url to the constructor.
3. Then you have to open up a new connection using HttpUrlConnection class.

I have included the complete code below for your reference. Please feel free to ask if you need more help. Thanks

```
package com.pragin.ocjp;

import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class JsonExample {

public String jsonEx(){
    String url = "  https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Place?lat=51.555504&lon=0.0592359&radius=80&includeChildren=False&type=NaptanPublicBusCoachTram&app_id=95a7b158&app_key=a3acd48055f470cf35ab5f6f360604c5";
    URL obj;
    BufferedReader reader;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder;
    HttpURLConnection con;
    stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        obj = new URL(url);
         con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode(); // to check success and failure of API call

        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
        String response = con.getResponseMessage();

        System.out.println("Response : " + response.toString());

        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));


        String line = null;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");

            System.out.println("String : " + stringBuilder.toString());
        }
        //return stringBuilder.toString();

    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("Error" + e);
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();

}

public void jsonParser(String res) throws ParseException {
    JSONParser jParse = new JSONParser();

    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jParse.parse(res);
    System.out.println("res = [" + jsonObject.size() + "]");
    for(int i = 0; i <jsonObject.size(); i++ ){
       // JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jArray.get(i);
       // jsonObject.
        String name = (String) jsonObject.get("$type");
        System.out.println("Name : " + name);
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    JsonExample js = new JsonExample();
    js.jsonParser(js.jsonEx());
}
```

}`